# Multi-Fields search using Span Queries with fuzziness in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Span queries to enable match phrase with fuzziness. I am able to do this on multiple fields but since i am using fuzzyquery with span_multi query, I am failing it to use this query for multiple fields based search. Is there a way that i can overcome this issue?

```
{
      "from": 0,
      "size": 10,

     "query": {
            "span_near" : {
                "clauses" : [
                   { 
                    "span_multi": {
                           "match": {
                                 "fuzzy": {
                                    "TITLE": {
                                           "fuzziness": "2",
                                            "value": "black"
                                                      }
                                            }
                                      }
                               }
                   },
                     { 
                    "span_multi": {
                           "match": {
                                 "fuzzy": {
                                    "TITLE": {
                                           "fuzziness": "2",
                                            "value": "box"
                                                      }
                                            }
                                      }
                               }
                   }

                ],
                "slop" : 2,
                "in_order" : true
            }
        },
      "highlight": {
        "type": "fvh",
        "fields": {
          "*": {}
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: hey Nikesh, I've mentioned multiple fields(*user.name* and *main_product*) in the section `Fuzzy with Phrase` in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53407151/fuzziness-in-bool-query-with-multimatch-elasticsearch/53409671#53409671 Let me know if that helps!