# fuzziness in bool query with multimatch elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

i am using elasticsearch version 6.3.0. I want to use fuzziness along with multimatch. but there is no option for that. Can anybody provide me a solution ? Thanks in advance 
Query :

```
    {   "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"function_score": {
              "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "local",
                  "fields": [
                      "user.name^3", 
                      "main_product"
                    ],
                    "type": "phrase"
                }
              }
            }}
          ], 
          "filter": {
            "geo_distance": {
              "distance": "1000km",

              "user.geolocation": {
                "lat": 25.55,
                "lon": -84.44
              }
            }
          }
        }   
} }
```

Answer (score 6):

Looking at your existing query, you are looking for mix of

- Boosting based on field
- Multifield match
- Phrase Matching
- Fuzzy Matching

If it isn't `phrase_match` you can simply add `"fuzziness": "AUTO"` or `"fuzziness":1 or whatever number based on your requirement` in your existing query and you'd get what you are looking for.

### Fuzzy without Phrase

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "function_score":{  
                  "query":{  
                     "multi_match":{  
                        "query":"local",
                        "fields":[  
                           "user.name^3",
                           "main_product"
                        ],
                        "fuzziness":"AUTO"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "filter":{  
            "geo_distance":{  
               "distance":"1000km",
               "user.geolocation":{  
                  "lat":25.55,
                  "lon":-84.44
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

### Fuzzy with Phrase:

In this case, you need to make use of [Span Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/span-queries.html)

I've discarded the filtering part just for the sake of simplicity and came up with the below query. And let's say that I am searching for phrase called `pearl jam`.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "function_score":{  
         "query":{  
            "bool":{  
               "should":[  
                  {  
                     "bool":{  
                        "boost":3,
                        "must":[  
                           {  
                              "span_near":{  
                                 "clauses":[  
                                    {  
                                       "span_multi":{  
                                          "match":{  
                                             "fuzzy":{  
                                                "user.name":"pearl"
                                             }
                                          }
                                       }
                                    },
                                    {  
                                       "span_multi":{  
                                          "match":{  
                                             "fuzzy":{  
                                                "user.name":"jam"
                                             }
                                          }
                                       }
                                    }
                                 ],
                                 "slop":0,
                                 "in_order":true
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "bool":{  
                        "boost":1,
                        "must":[  
                           {  
                              "span_near":{  
                                 "clauses":[  
                                    {  
                                       "span_multi":{  
                                          "match":{  
                                             "fuzzy":{  
                                                "main_product":"pearl"
                                             }
                                          }
                                       }
                                    },
                                    {  
                                       "span_multi":{  
                                          "match":{  
                                             "fuzzy":{  
                                                "main_product":"jam"
                                             }
                                          }
                                       }
                                    }
                                 ],
                                 "slop":0,
                                 "in_order":true
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So what I am doing is performing *boosting based on fields in multi-field phrase with fuzzy match* for phrase called `pearl jam`.

Having `slop: 0` and `in_order:true` would enable me to do phrase match for the words I've specified in the clauses.

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Hi Kamal, You are mentioning two different fields explicitly in two different must queries. I have to perform the same query over 100 fields. How do I perform this kind of search?

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible with Span Queries. You would need to rewrite the query for the fields. If you are creating the query on your service layer, you can come up with a loop that would run through all the fields and thereby construct the query for each and every field you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your response  Kamal, Unfortunately that is not a case in my Service layer since i don't have the information of the fields at the service layer.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think there is no option for fuzziness on a multi-match query?

For example, with the data below:

```
http://localhost:9200/question_1/doc/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"name" : "John Lazy", "text": "lazzi"}
{"index":{}}
{"name" : "John Lassi", "text": "lasso"}
{"index":{}}
{"name" : "Joan Labbe", "text": "lazzy"}
```

And this query:

```
http://localhost:9200/question_1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "lazi",
      "fields" : [ "name", "text" ],
      "fuzziness": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Then I get one result, but if I change the `fuzziness` parameter to `2` I'll get three results.